# Rails 5, "nil is not a valid asset source"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have just upgraded to Rails 5 and I have a weird issue while trying to show an image.

I have the exact code I had for Rails 4:

```
<%= image_tag article.image_url(:thumb) %>
```

But after upgrading I get:

```
nil is not a valid asset source
```

Before upgrading to Rails 5, **I didn't have any similar issue**.

What could be at fault here?  Can it be something else and not a Rails upgrade issue?

Comment: It looks like you just don't have an image in this record. Could you confirm it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to show an image that **did not exist**.

Adding `unless article.image.blank?` solved it:

```
<%= image_tag article.image_url(:thumb) unless article.image.blank? %>
```

**EDIT:**  In **Rails 4**, this would have just rendered nothing without errors, while in 
**Rails 5** it raises an error. So it was, in fact, an upgrade issue.

Big thanks to @BookOfGreg for pointing this out.

Comment: For those getting here without carrierwave: In rails 4, this would have rendered out an empty img tag, in rails 5 it will raise on nil, so there is a small difference.

Comment: In solidarity. .

Comment: Ibid. Also, default images not present will raise this error in Rails 5 and it can take a fair bit of hunting to find the cause.

Comment: If you still need to create an `<img>` tag even if the image is not available, you can use `content_tag(:img, nil, src: "...", alt: "...")` (maybe because you set its source with JavaScript later).

Comment: it is better to avoid `unless`. The above code can be changed to

`<%= image_tag article.image_url(:thumb) if article.image.present? %>`

Comment: @ViC I think in this case it is exactly the same using `unless`...`blank` and `if`...`present`.  It would be bad to use unless if we had something like `unless`...`!blank` which makes the person reading the code to think in double negation

Answer (score 10):

I don't know this is compact solution or not but this code will work.

activate the fallback method in your uploader.

```
  def default_url
    "/assets/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end
```

Hope this will help you.

Cheers (y)

Comment: I already solved it, but I forgot to update this post. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, you need to add **unless** condition in your code. You need to add below code

> <%= image_tag article.image_url(:thumb) unless article.image.blank? %>

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code snippet will help those future readers.

```
<td><%= image_tag image.picture.url, size: "100x100" unless image.picture.url.blank? %></td>
```

without that `unless image.picture.url.blank?` part of the code,

> "nil is not a valid asset source"

shows up when uploading empty image.