# Rails 5 Minitest ActionView::Template::Error: nil is not a valid asset source

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I upgraded my Rails Application from 4.2 -> 5.0.0.1.

Other **TESTS** works fine (e.g. Model, Helper, Feature), but havinf trouble with my **Controller Test**.

I have read about **Keyword arguments in controller & integration tests** in Rails 5. So I changed the code structure as given below...

**ActionView::Template::Error: nil is not a valid asset source**

```
setup do
  @logo = plogos(:main_logo)
end

test "should get edit" do
  puts @logo.id // just to check...working fine 
  get :edit, params: {id: @logo.id}
  assert_response :success
end
```

But I got new error with **ActionView**.

Is there anyone encountered and fixed the same issue, please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add some logtrace, probably it hints you where it went wrong.

May it be that the main_logo-fixture doesn't have an image? Since Rails 5 `image_tag` raises this error when given an `nil`-value, see also: [Rails, "nil is not a valid asset source" for a particular image_tag (Carrierwave)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530024/rails-nil-is-not-a-valid-asset-source-for-a-particular-image-tag-carrierwave)

Besides that, typically the new scaffolded code would look as follows:

```
require 'test_helper'
class LogosControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @logo = plogos(:main_logo)
  end
  #...
  test "should get edit" do
    get edit_logo_url(@logo)
    assert_response :success
  end
  #... 
end
```